# ArrayList без смещений

Tags: java

Есть ArrayList, используется add(Index, Object), при удалении элемента(по индексу) индексы в ArrayList смещаются и я теряю индекс и не могу обратится к нему. Как решить проблему?

Comment: можно `Map` использовать, с индексом в роли ключа

Comment: Это и есть корректная работа `ArrayList`'а, не надо пытаться заставить его работать иначе. Можете пояснить, что именно вы пытаетесь реализовать?
Если элементы жестко привязаны к своим индексам, нужно использовать `map` с ключом `Integer` вместо `List`'a с индексами, или же массив `int[]` - у него не меняется индексация.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать ArrayList, то можете не удалять элемент, а заменить его на null - set(int index, null). Таким образом индекс сохранится.

Comment: На null? интересно, попробую

Comment: Думаю мне надо использовать map, но какой map? без синхронизации

Comment: `HashMap` - простой `map` без синхронизации;
`LinkedHashMap` - `map` без синхронизации с сохранением порядка доступа к элементам (чтения/записи);
`Hashtable` - простой `map` с синхронизацией;
Если скажете подробней, что пытаетесь реализовать, то можно будет конкретней ответить на ваш вопрос "но какой map?".